# How can I make Ruby's SOAP::RPC::Driver work with self signed certificates?

Tags: ruby, soap, ssl

How can I prevent this exception when making a soap call to a server that is using a self signed certificate?

```
require "rubygems"
gem "httpclient", "2.1.2"
require 'http-access2'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
client = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new( url, 'http://removed' )
client.options[ 'protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode' ] = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
client.options[ 'protocol.http.basic_auth' ] << [ url, user, pass ]

at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/streamHandler.rb:200:in `send_post': 415:  (SOAP::HTTPStreamError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/streamHandler.rb:109:in `send'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:170:in `route'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:141:in `call'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/rpc/driver.rb:178:in `call'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
client.options["protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode"] = nil
```

Comment: Security issue. Dangerous. But it will work, yes. (ps - was not me)

Comment: that's some very dangerous advice!