# Ruby SOAP SSL Woes

Tags: ruby, soap, ssl

I have a SOAP client in Ruby that I'm trying to get working with a Ruby SOAP server, to no avail. The client works fine over SSL with a Python SOAP server, but not with the Ruby version. Here's what the server looks like:

```
require 'soap/rpc/standaloneServer'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'httpclient'

def cert(filename)
  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("path to cert.cert") { |f|
    f.read
  })
end

def key(filename)
  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("path to rsaprivate.key") { |f|
    f.read
  })
end

class Server < SOAP::RPC::HTTPServer
 ~code snipped for readability~
end

server = Server.new(:BindAddress => HelperFunctions.local_ip, :Port => 1234, :SSLCertificate => cert("path to cert"), :SSLPrivateKey => key("path to rsa private key"))
new_thread = Thread.new { server.start }
```

I've trimmed some of the code out for readability's sake (e.g., I have some methods in there I expose) and it works fine with SSL off. But when the client tries to connect, it sees this:

```
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:567: warning: using default DH parameters.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I tried taking some advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128660/how-can-i-make-rubys-soaprpcdriver-work-with-self-signed-certificates) and now I see this message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/httpconfigloader.rb:64:in `set_ssl_config': SSL not supported (NotImplementedError)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but for a client. I tried `require 'webrick/https'` to no avail. Have you had success on the client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arg. I was trying to follow along [this link](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/108292) and it turns out I was missing a simple include statement:

```
require 'webrick/https'
```

That, combined with the help from the link in the original question solves the problem. Hopefully this saves someone else down the line an hour of grief :)

Answer (score 1):

"SSL not supported" can be caused by not having httpclient installed.

Answer (score 0):

Me too.. and don't forget to put the :SSLEnable => true spend couple of hours figuring that out...

```
server = Server.new(:BindAddress => HelperFunctions.local_ip, :Port => 1234, :SSLEnable => true, :SSLCertificate => cert("path to cert"), :SSLPrivateKey => key("path to rsa private key"))
```