# How can I make Ruby’s SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory work with self signed certificates?

Tags: ruby, wsdl, self-signed

This post is somewhat similar to this other post:

[How can I make Ruby's SOAP::RPC::Driver work with self signed certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128660/how-can-i-make-rubys-soaprpcdriver-work-with-self-signed-certificates)

except I'm using WSDLDriverFactory:

```
@loginWsdlUrl = 'https://localhost:9843/services/LoginService?wsdl'
loginClient = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(@loginWsdlUrl)
loginClient.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode' ] = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

WSDLDriverFactory opens the URL inside the .new() method so it seems impossible to set any options first.  I never get to the .options[] line.

How can I set the options ahead of time?  Or, install a do-nothing verifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loginClient.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode' ] = nil

Comment: You didn't read the post. The connection is initiated inside of the .new() call, setting the option after the fact won't solve anything.

Comment: I read the post, but misread that you're using WSDLFactory.  You're probably going to have to pull the WSDL out-of-band and use the locally cached copy to run WSDLfactory against.